# Why is my linked list being sorted incorrectly?

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to insert new appointments sorted by date to a linked list but when I go to test it, there is always one instance where it is not sorted correctly. Currently this is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

class VaccList:
    class Appointment:
        def __init__(self, name, age, city, date):
            assert type(name) is str, 'name variable must be a string'
            assert type(age) is int, 'age variable must be a integer'
            assert type(city) is str, 'city variable must be a string'
            assert type(date) is datetime, 'date variable must be a datetime object'
            assert name != None, 'name variable cannot be empty'
            assert age >= 18 and age <= 100, 'age must be between 18 and 100'
            #   ADD 6 asserts.  4 for the types and name cannot be empty, 
            #   and age must be between 18 and 100

            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.city = city
            self.date = date
            self.confirmed = False
            self.next = None

        def __str__(self):
            s = "Appointment for " + self.name + " on " + str(self.date) + " age:" + str(self.age) + "  city:" + self.city
            if self.confirmed:
                s += " (confirmed)"
            else:
                s += " (unconfirmed)"
            return s

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def print(self):       #YOU WRITE THIS (EASY)
        '''
        Print all the appointments, one per line.  Print a blank line after the last one.
        If the list is empty, print a line saying the Appointment List is empty.
        '''
        runner = self.head
        while runner != None:
            print(runner)
            runner = runner.next
    

    def insertByDate(self, newAppt):          #### YOU WRITE (HARD)
        ''' Given a pointer to an Appointment object, put it into the list so that the list remains sorted by date.
           Obviously the linked list may be empty, which is easy.  But inserting the newAppt in sorted order
           may mean putting it at the front if the newAppt's date is less than the first.  Or at the end, or in
           the middle.
        '''
        assert type(newAppt) is VaccList.Appointment, 'insertByDate requires a pointer to an appointment object'
        newnode = newAppt

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newAppt
        elif newAppt.date < self.head.date:
            newAppt.next = self.head
            self.head = newAppt
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next != None and current.date < newAppt.date:
                current = current.next
            newAppt.next = current.next
            current.next = newAppt
```

This is the test code that I am attempting to run:

```
active =VaccList()

appt = VaccList.Appointment("Henry", 72, "Buffalo", datetime(2021,5,1,12,0,0))
active.insertByDate(appt)
appt = VaccList.Appointment("John", date=datetime(2021,3,10,12,0,0), age=75, city="Buffalo")
active.insertByDate(appt)
appt = VaccList.Appointment(date = datetime(2021, 3, 5, 8, 0, 0), name="Mary", city="Buffalo", age=65)
active.insertByDate(appt)
appt = VaccList.Appointment(date = datetime(2021, 4, 28, 13, 30, 0), name="Alvin", city="New York City", age=39)
active.insertByDate(appt)
appt = VaccList.Appointment(date = datetime(2021, 4, 21, 14, 0, 0), name="Sheila", city="New York City", age=50)
active.insertByDate(appt)
appt = VaccList.Appointment(date = datetime(2021, 3, 12, 18, 0, 0), name="Melvin", city="New York City", age=80)
active.insertByDate(appt)

active.print()
```

However everytime I run this the appointment under 'Henry' is sorted incorrectly. I am lost because it seems to sort the rest of the appointments just fine except for 'Henry' being out of place. any ideas/solutions are really appreciated as this is one of my first python projects.

```
Appointment for Mary on 2021-03-05 08:00:00 age:65  city:Buffalo (unconfirmed)
Appointment for John on 2021-03-10 12:00:00 age:75  city:Buffalo (unconfirmed)
Appointment for Henry on 2021-05-01 12:00:00 age:72  city:Buffalo (unconfirmed)
Appointment for Melvin on 2021-03-12 18:00:00 age:80  city:New York City (unconfirmed)
Appointment for Sheila on 2021-04-21 14:00:00 age:50  city:New York City (unconfirmed)
Appointment for Alvin on 2021-04-28 13:30:00 age:39  city:New York City (unconfirmed)
```

Comment: The more interesting question would be: why reinventing the wheel? Why not using built in lists? Would save a lot of time, effort and would be less error prone.

Comment: Aaaah, now I see it - homework (# YOU WRITE THIS) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else` block, your loop is finding a `current` node such that its date comes after the date of the node you want to insert. But realise how that brings you one node too far... You will insert the new node *after* `current`, so `current` must still be a node that has a date that comes *before* the one you are inserting.

So change this:

```
 while current.next != None and current.date < newAppt.date:
```

to:

```
 while current.next != None and current.next.date < newAppt.date:
 #                                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it! I was staring at this until the middle of the night and could not figure out what was going wrong.